# Deserialize XML to string/object/List of objects from HTTP response

Tags: c#, xml, http, deserialization

I have a Xamarin.Forms App and get a `response.Content` in XML format. How to Deserialize the data in different types in different responses ex. string , object , list .
This is my code:

```
          client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
                    var response = await client.GetAsync($"api/users");
                    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {
                        var pom = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                        ///// xml logic here
                        return pom;
                    }
                    else
                    {

                        return null;
                    }
```

**UPDATE**

I receive : `<test> TEst </test>`
how to convert that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Deserialize XML document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/364253/how-to-deserialize-xml-document)

Comment: If response.Content is a string you first need to put into a stream : StringReader reader = new StringReader(response.Content);.  The you can create a XmlReader : XmlReader xReader = XmlReader.Create(reader);  Then you can use any Xml Serialization like Alexander links.

Comment: @AlexanderPope when i get only one string like in this situation: what is XMLroot what is XML ELEMENT?

Comment: i get just this <test> Test </test>

Comment: Are all the properties in your classes public?  Does xml have namespaces?  Do you have any array?  Serialization is uppercase/lowercase so does the class/property names exactly match the tag names in the xml?